# Add content within a nested div, and not change look of it's container

Tags: css

At the moment I have a container div

```
#container {
   margin: 0 auto;
   margin-top: 10px;
   width:800px;
   background-color:#eaeced;
}
```

within that div I'd like to add a content box which I've done like this

```
#contentbox {
   background-color: #fff;
   width: 400px;
   margin: 5px;
}
```

As soon as I write some text into the `#contentbox div`.. this div covers the whole of the `#container div`... I have tried using padding but this increases the original size of the container..

I've just tried to add `margin: 5px;` but this will create the space only on the sides.. not on the top or the bottom.. :(

Sorry I'm quite new at this and would appreciate some help

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a lot of information, but I think what you're after is something like this:

```
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 790px;
    background-color:#eaeced;
    padding: 5px;
}

#contentbox {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 1px 0;
}

p {margin: 1em 0;}
```

presuming HTML like this:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="contentbox">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p> 
  </div>
</div>
```

first of all move the required padding onto the `#container`, you can adjust the width of the `#container` to be your required width, less the total left/right padding  - this will keep the width of the box as you want.

Then you have [collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins) going on  - though margin collapsing is correct behaviour you won't see it in IE unless you add specific margins - adding a specific margin to the `<p>` or any other content in the box will be required to get consistent behaviour even though it's the opposite of what you probably want.. the `p` should have default margins and they're what's collapsing outside the the `#contentbox` in some browsers (e.g. FF).. once you add specific margin all browser will then exhibit collapsing margin behaviour though some collapse the background internally and some externally so it looks weird.. **however**

adding 1px top/bottom padding (or a border would do it too) to the the inner `#contentbox` will fix that and make sure the actual content margins stay inside the content box

The result is I think what you're looking for.. but if not leave a comment or update your question with some code or a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example